# Qual ferramenta utilizar para gerar releases em Java?

Tags: java, api, maven, release

Estou desenvolvendo meu primeiro projeto em Java, a aplicação é uma API utilizando várias bibliotecas, entre elas: Jetty, Hibernate, HttpClient, JasperReport...

Nesse projeto eu utilizo o framework Maven, eu gostaria de saber quais ferramentas utilizar para gerar releases em Java?

Comment: Como está, a pergunta está difícil de responder. O que exatamente você chama de `gerar releases`? Que tipo de funcionalidade/comportamento você espera?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Gerar um release é algo bem amplo e envolve muitas coisas. Mas o mais básico pode ser conseguido com o próprio maven, via "release:prepare" e "release:perform". Mais detalhes sobre o plugin "release" podem ser encontrados na [documentação oficial](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/).

Com base então nos comentários desta respostas: com o Maven, você especifica o tipo de projeto que você tem (jar, war, ear), e o maven gera o artefato automaticamente via "mvn package". O pacote fica no diretório "target". As bibliotecas que são definidas como dependências "normais" (scope=compile, ou sem escopo definido), são colocadas no pacote final, caso seja um war ou ear. Caso seja um jar, você precisa utilizar um plugin como o ["assembly"](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/), que vai acabar gerando um grande jar com todas as dependências incluídas.

Comment: Acredito que a dúvida dele seja como empacotar os jars que o maven cria, qual a conveção utilizada para deploy java, se é só o jar, se deve-se juntar os jars em um, se deve-se levar a jvm, se cria-se um instalador. Inclusive estas são dúvidas minhas.

Comment: Acabei deixando muito amplo a pergunta, essas perguntas que o leogaldioli fez entra no contexto da minha dúvida.

Comment: Ok, mudei um pouco a resposta para incluir algo a mais, mas seria interessante especificar o problema que está tendo, senão, fica difícil saber o que você já fez e o que você já sabe :-)

Answer (score 2):

Alternativamente ao **Maven**, você pode usar o **Gradle**. É uma ferramenta que automatiza os Builds e Testes, e é muito simples de trabalhar, e que utiliza o imenso repositório do próprio Maven. Eu comecei a mexer com ela a 2 dias, e estou gostando muito. O arquivo de definição do projeto, o "gradle.build" é muito mais fácil de trabalhar e ler do que o "pom.xml"

Segundo a definição da homepage do Gradle: "*... combina o poder e flexibilidade do Ant, com o gerenciamento de dependências e convenções do Maven...*"

Mais info: 
http://www.gradle.org/